# How to use process.start runas in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core, winui-3, shellexecute

When I tried to use code below to launch a high privilege process from a low one,a uac popout and the something.exe(C# console app with some dll) stucks without giving any output or error, and ocupying quite some cpu.Everything is fine if I run the Something.exe by right clicking it and run as administrator.Why??? I have tried Fody.Costura or set the workingdirectory but the problem wasn't solved(seems not a dll issue). I am using .net core6 and windows app sdk `1.2.230217.4`

```
Process P = new Process();
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
P.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
P.StartInfo.FileName = ApplicationHelper.GetFullPathToExe() + "\\Win64\\SomeThing.exe";
P.StartInfo.Arguments = msg;
P.Start();
```

Comment: Is this WinUI 3 app packaged or non-packaged?

Comment: @Andrew It's a packaged one

Comment: I created a sample app and at least it works. My first guess is that the ``FileName`` path is not correct. Can you try using an absolute path that is outside packaged app?

Comment: Can a simple console application be started? I cannot reproduce it under the administrator account.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding The FileName is correct, if useshellexcute = false the program could run without some fuction, I tried what you said,move the exe outside the packaged app and it works,thanks. But why would this happen?It's so weird

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I think Andrew's comment provide a solution. the exe is a simple .net 472 console application.if useshellexcute = false the program could run without some fuction, but useshellexecute = true and verb = runas the application could not work

Comment: BTW, packaged app also worked for me. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Create a plain console app named "Something.exe".
2. Manually copy "Something.exe" folder, "net6.0" in my case, to the WinUI 3 app's **LocalState** folder. (You can automatically do this with [MSBuild Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022) task.)
3. In your WinUI 3 app call this code:

```cs
// This is the path for the "LocalState" folder.
string directory = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

Process P = new();
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
P.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
P.StartInfo.FileName = $@"{directory}\net6.0\Something.exe";
P.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
P.Start();
```

Comment: A possible explanation is that [the packaged app runs inside an app container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#types-of-desktop-app). There is [AppContainer Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/appcontainer-isolation).